# this method crashes if I use a property and works fine if I declare the variable within the method--why?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I'm working on a programmable calculator, and for the life of me I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here are the relevant parts of the code.  (The code is unfinished, so I know there's extra stuff floating around.)

CalculatorViewController.m

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userIsEnteringNumber;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL numberIsNegative;
@property (nonatomic,strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *arrayOfDictionaries;
@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *dictionary;
@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController
@synthesize display = _display;
@synthesize history = _history;
@synthesize userIsEnteringNumber = _userIsEnteringNumber;
@synthesize numberIsNegative;
@synthesize brain = _brain;
@synthesize arrayOfDictionaries;
@synthesize dictionary;

-(CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
if (!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
return _brain;
}

/*snip code for some other methods*/

- (IBAction)variablePressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
NSString *var = sender.currentTitle; 
NSDictionary *dict = [self.dictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3],@"x",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:4.1],@"y",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:-6],@"z",[NSNumber numberWithDouble:8.7263],@"foo",nil];
[self.brain convertVariable:var usingDictionary:dict];
self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",var];
self.history.text = [self.history.text stringByAppendingString:sender.currentTitle];
[self.brain pushOperand:[dict objectForKey:var] withDictionary:dict];
}

@end
```

And here's CalculatorBrain.m.

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorBrain ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *operandStack;
@end

@implementation CalculatorBrain
@synthesize operandStack = _operandStack;


-(void)pushOperand:(id)operand withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
NSNumber *operandAsObject;
if (![operand isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    operandAsObject = operand;
}
else 
{
    operandAsObject = [dictionary objectForKey:operand];
}
[self.operandStack addObject:operandAsObject];
}

-(double)popOperand
{
NSNumber *operandAsObject = [self.operandStack lastObject];
if (operandAsObject) [self.operandStack removeLastObject];
return [operandAsObject doubleValue];
}

-(double)convertVariable:(NSString *)variable usingDictionary:dictionary
{
double convertedNumber = [[dictionary objectForKey:variable] doubleValue];
return convertedNumber;
}

@end
```

The thing I'm having trouble understanding is in the `CalculatorViewController.m` method `- (IBAction)variablePressed:(UIButton *)sender`.  This line crashes the program:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.dictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:[list of objects and keys]];
```

But if I make it

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[list of objects and keys]];
```

then everything works fine.  But if I try to do

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[self.dictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[list of objects and keys]];
```

which seems to me the right thing to do, then XCode won't let me, so I'm obviously not understanding something.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+alloc` allocates memory for an object. `-init...` methods initialize the object.

`[self.dictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:...` calls `-dictionary` which is either going to return a dictionary set in that property or nil and then attempts to call `init...` on it. If the dictionary exists then you are attempting to initialize an object more than once which is not valid. If the property has not been set then the getter will return nil and sending an `init...` message to nil will do nothing. Either way this is not what you want to do.

`[[self.dictionary alloc] init...` is also invalid, as the compiler warns you. Now you try to obtain an object from `-dictionary` and then call the class method `+alloc` on it.

There seems to be some fundamental confusion here about how objects are created and what property accessors do. I'm not sure how to address that besides suggesting looking at [object creation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH39-SW1) and [dot syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17).

Comment: "Fundamental confusion" hits the nail on the head (for most of life, actually, not just programming).  Thanks for the explanation, which is clear and helpful.  I'll take a look at those links....

Comment: @JoelDerfner please feel free to ask for help with that confusion. I'm just not sure what your next question is and so hesitate to guess what you might want explained.

Comment: Ah--wait--I realized where I was led astray.  I mean, the fundamental confusion is still there, but I think I started from a less confused place.  But the question is:  if I've declared an `NSDictionary` property, which means, as you say, that it already exists, how then do I populate it without something like `initWithObjectsAndKeys`?  I can just use an NSMutableDictionary, of course, but it would be good to know still....

Comment: "that it already exists" --> "that the dictionary already exists"

Comment: First, declaring a property does not create an object. `@property (nonatomic) NSDictionary *dictionary;` tells us that instances of class `CalculatorViewController` will have a getter method `- (NSDictionary *)dictionary` and a setter method `- (void)setDictionary:(NSDictionary *)theDictionary`. At this point all we've said is that those methods will exist. `@synthesize dictionary;` creates the default versions of the getter and setter methods for the property so that you don't have to write them yourself. Again, we haven't created any instances of `NSDictionary` yet, just a place to store one

Comment: Once we have declared a property (in this case giving us a way to store an instance of `NSDictionary` "in" an instance of `CalculatorViewController`) then if we create an object we can choose to store it in that property: `self.dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init...]`. That dot syntax is just a short hand for `[self setDictionary:[[NSDictionary alloc] init...]]`. Similarly any `= self.dictionary` is equivalent to `= [self dictionary]`, a call to our synthesized getter method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14721/discussion-between-jonah-and-joel-derfner)